# Dunavant integration rules of order 11

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

To integrate a function over a (reference) triangle $T$, Dunavant rules are commonly used. The integral over $T$ is approximated by the sum
$$\int_T f(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^N w_k f(x_k, y_k).$$

The values of $w_k$ and $(x_k, y_k)$ can be found, e.g., in the original paper http://maxwell.sze.hu/~marcsa/docs/277540.pdf.

Examining the table for higher orders, I've noted a strange thing: for all orders up to 10, all the $N$ points are inside $T$, but for the order 11,  some of them fall outside $T$. This also happens, e.g., for the order 15.

Is there any special reason for this behavior? Are there similar rules for which all points are inside $T$? After all, if we integrate a function over a triangle, it doesn't have to be defined outside it.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but perhaps this is a reason to not use high-order Dunavant rules, similar to how negative quadrature weights indicate that high-order Newton-Cotes rules are numerically undesirable?